# How can I fix this broken text in terminal after applying agnoster zsh theme?

Tags: text, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, iterm2

[image]

Hi all!

I applied "agnoster" zsh theme to the iterm2 and then texts appeared as question marks in my terminal.

How can I fix it?

I already downloaded fonts and applied them but nothing changed..

Please let me know!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What do you mean by **applying** fonts? How is your `LANG` setting? BTW, this question is perhaps more about configuration, and should be asked on [su] instead.

Comment: Did you figure out how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I used "powerlevel10k" theme for my zsh. I also had same issue with you. It might be a font issue. So Please change your terminal font using profile configuration ("cmd"+"," button).

https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k#meslo-nerd-font-patched-for-powerlevel10k

In my case, "MesloLGS NF Regular" is worked.

However, I highly recommend you use iterm2. There is no problem to use it.

```
brew install iterm2
```